# On click event triggers submission of both forms

Tags: javascript, onclick

I Have a drop down box which once clicked updates the pagination results for my MYSQL query results and this works fine.  The problem i have is that there are two forms on the page, the first for the pagination drop down box and the second for some additional filters.

When I click to up date the pagination result, the onlick element submits data from both forms, instead of just the pagination form.

I am new to javascript and so i may have the wrong idea but i thought that the javascript would only submit the data from the form with the name / id of form.

HTML for pagination drop down box.

```
 <form id="form" name="form" method="GET" action="">
         <label for="pagination"></label>
            <select name="pagination" id="pagination">
              <option value="10">10 Items Per Page</option>
              <option value="20">20 Items Per Page</option>
              <option value="30">30 Items Per Page</option>
              <option value="40">40 Items Per Page</option>
              <option value="50">50 Items Per Page</option>
              <option value="75">75 Items Per Page</option>
             </select>
       </form>
```

HTML For Second Form

```
         <form name="filter" id="filter" method="GET" action="visitor_list8.php">

            <label for="referrer"></label>
              <select name="referrer" id="referrer">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Adwords">Adwords</option>
                <option value="Bing">Bing</option>
                <option value="Direct">Direct</option>
                <option value="Google">Google</option>
                <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
               </select>

             <label for="visitor_type"></label>
               <select name="visitor_type" id="visitor_type">
                 <option value="">Select</option>
                 <option value="Not Set">New</option>
                 <option value="returning">Returning</option>
               </select>

              <label for="sortby"></label>
                <select name="sortby" id="sortby">
                 <option value="">Select</option>
                 <option value="timedate">Date / Time</option>
                 <option value="page_views">Page Views</option>
                 <option value="referrer">Referrer</option>
                 <option value="search_term">Search Term</option>
                 <option value="visitor_type">Visitor Type</option>
                 <option value="company_name">Company Name</option>
                 </select>

      <input type="submit" name="button" id="btn-submit" class="btn-submit" value="Submit">
           </form>
```

Javascript

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#pagination').change(function() {
              $('form').submit();
                       });
                     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$('form').submit();` to `$('#form').submit();`

`$('form').submit();` will submit every form on the page, while
`$('#form').submit();` will submit the form with the id `form`.

Maybe consider changing the `form` id to something else to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to submit the form containing the select

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pagination').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#form').submit();
```

Thus you only trigger the submit on the specified form instead of triggering them all.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your selector is too general. $('#form').submit() or $('#filter').submit().